# Javascript redirect to html

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to let javascript redirect to another html file using window.location but it keeps reloading. Here is the Javascript

```js
var myStorage = window.localStorage;
let accounts = [{
  username: 'admin',
  pass: 'admin123!',
  email: 'admin@gmail.com'
}];
myStorage.setItem("account", accounts);

//check login account
var checkLogin = function() {
  let uname = document.getElementById("Uname").value;
  let pass = document.getElementById("Pass").value;
  if (uname == "admin" && pass == "admin123!") {
    myStorage.setItem("user", {
      username: 'admin',
      pass: 'admin123!',
      email: 'admin@gmail.com'
    });
    alert("Login admin");
    window.location = "../account/myaccount.html";
    alert("redirect");
  } else {
    myStorage.setItem("user", undefined);
    document.getElementById("incorrectAccount").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("incorrectAccount").innerHTML = "Incorrect Username or Password";
  }
};
```

```html
<form id="login" method="post" onsubmit="return checkLogin();">
  <div>
    <label><b>Username:     
                </b>    
                </label>
    <input type="text" name="Uname" id="Uname" placeholder="admin"><br><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><b>Password: </b></label>
    <input type="Password" name="Pass" id="Pass" placeholder="admin123!"><br><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="log" id="log" value="Log In"></a>
    <span id="incorrectAccount"></span>
    <br><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <span>Remember me</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="../account/recover.html">Forgot Password?</a>
    <br><br>
    <a href="../account/register.html">Register</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

After typing the same username and the password, the first alert works and then it skips the redirect link and goes straight for the 2nd alert message

Comment: `window.location.href = "../account/myaccount.html";` try this.

Comment: @BOZ — That won't make a difference.

Comment: Please, use JSON.stringify to stringify the data you save to localStorage.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless. (And use them consistently, you have a span instead of a label for "Remember me")

Comment: Use CSS. Don't use `<b>` or simulate margins using multiple line breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submitting a form will cause the page to load the URL specified in the `action` attribute, which defaults to the current URL, which gives that effect though.

You must be trigging the JS when you submit the form. The JS runs, then the form submits, and the URL being navigated to changes.

You need to [prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of the form submission event.

e.g.

```
var checkLogin = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

and

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', checkLogin);
```

---

Re edit.

This is the problem. However, you are using event binding methods from before they introduced `addEventListener` (which became a standard in November 2000).

If you want to use intrinsic event attributes (I don't recommend them, they have some confusing gotchas) then you need to return `false` from the event handler.

> ```
> onsubmit="return checkLogin();"
> ```

You are currently returning the return value of `checkLogin`, but that doesn't have a `return` statement so it returns `undefined`. You need to return `false` and not any falsy value.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myRedirect() {
  location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com")
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myRedirect()">Replace document</button>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it did not really work

Comment: I don't understand how you think this code-only-explanation-free answer solves the problem.